# Correlation vs Derivative

Tags: calculus, statistics

Is a statistical correlation and derivative (in calculus) the same thing? I ask because a teacher gave an example in which the derivative between happiness and coffee was positive. In other words, as coffee consumption goes up so should happiness. This sounds like a correlation but I've never heard anyone mention the connection between statistics and calculus.

Comment: "I've never heard anyone mention the connection between statistics and calculus..." Neither did I. Btw, correlation is symmetric. Derivative (as relation of two functions, where one is the derivative of the other) is not.

Comment: I think that is an interesting observation. Indeed if one variable tends to increase (decrease) on average when another one does, they are positively (negatively) correlated. If the increase(decrease) is smooth and deterministic, the derivative is positive (negative).  I don't know how quantative this is.

Comment: Correlation is a dependence between two random variables (in the narrow sense, linear). Functional dependence is the strongest form of dependence, a perfect correlation. In reality, happiness and coffee are not perfectly correlated, but in your teacher's simplified model it was imagined that one is a monotone function of another, so the derivative is positive. In general, it makes no sense to talk of derivatives of a correlation, see [Correlation and dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence).